# Jquery json response iteration with condition

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json response...

```
{
"albums": {
  "data": [
     {
        "created_time": "2011-12-29T11:29:03+0000",
        "id": "10150573478667193",
        "name": "Timeline Photos",
        "photos": {
           "data": [
              {
                 "created_time": "2014-09-04T06:45:15+0000",
                 "source": "https://link.jpg",
                 "id": "10152743142372193",
                 "likes": {
                    "data": [
                       {
                          "id": "10202250935623343",
                          "name": "Name LastName"
                       }
                    ],
                    "summary": {
                       "total_count": 13
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
  }
 }
}
```

The actual response has a lot more album objects and photos objects but i shortened it for showing...Now what i am trying to do is iterate throught response and get the "source" link for the photo that has the highest total_count(most liked photo) in a couple of albums.I managed to get the highest total_count but i cant get the "source" link.Here is how i got highest total_count-

```
var array=[];
$.each(response.albums.data,function(index,obj){
            //console.log("index1:" + index + " object1:" +obj);
            $.each(obj,function(index2,obj2){
            //console.log("index2:" + index2 + " object2:" +obj2);
            if(typeof obj2 == 'object'){
                $.each(obj2.data,function(index3,obj3){
                //console.log("index3:" + index3 + " object3:" +obj3);
                        $.each(obj3,function(index4,obj4){
                        //console.log("index4:" + index4 + " object4:" +obj4);
                            if(typeof obj4 == 'object'){
                                $.each(obj4,function(index5,obj5){
                                //console.log("index5:" + index5 + " object5:" +obj5);
                                    if(index5 == 'summary'){
                                        $.each(obj5,function(index6,obj6){
                                            //console.log("index6:" + index6 + " object6:" +obj6);
                                            array[array.length] = obj6; 



                                        });

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });         
                });
            }
            }); 
        });
        var mostLikedNumber=Math.max.apply(Math,array);
        console.log("Most liked - " +mostLikedNumber);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't see you using `jQuery.parseJSON()` to access the object data? - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: its my first time parsing json,i did it like this without that function and i got my count but the rest i cant do.

Comment: Why not make use of jQuery, it was intended for this purpose and seeing as you're already using it with other functions it seems a bit like creating work for yourself for no reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your script is overly complicated:

```
var mostLikes = -1;
var mostLiked = [];

$.each(response.albums.data, function (idx, album) {
    $.each(album.photos.data, function (idx, photo) {
        if (photo.likes.summary.total_count > mostLikes) {
            mostLikes = photo.likes.summary.total_count;
            mostLiked = [photo.source];
        } else if (photo.likes.summary.total_count == mostLikes) {
            mostLiked.push(photo.source);
        }
    });
});

console.log("Most liked - " + mostLiked.join(",") + " = " + mostLikes);
```

This accounts for ties as well.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/dc84k3x0/

Comment: i tried your code but on if condition there is error-"photo.likes is undefined".

Comment: i just added if(typeof photo.likes != 'undefined'){} over the existing if condition and it is working now...it happened because some photos doesnt have likes so they are undefined.Anyways big thanks!